# how to implement Auth Directive In Apollo Sever graphql?

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I have following typeDefs

```
type User{
    id:String
    name:String
    role:Role
    ...
}

type Product{
    id:String
    name:String
    ...
}

enum Role{
    ADMIN
    USER
}
```

So In this case, I want access the mutation only when logged in user admin.
So it is possible to manage it  through middleware that check over all mutations and queries to whether user role is admin or user?